# How to iterate and sum each element in a list with another to find a number?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures, python-itertools

I was taking a programming challenge and this question encountered, I somehow got stuck with it.
I was given a list:
`[10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 15]`
And I had to find if the sum of any element in this would provide a result 30 and output should be the count
As we could see we have two possibilities, 10+20 = 30 and 15+15, so the count is 2.
But how to do it, should it be using for loop or itertools or any slicing or functional solution?

Comment: Do you need sum of two elements?

Comment: @Laszlowaty yes sum of two elements, but the answer has been given in comment already. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itetools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and a generator expression within [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) :

```
>>> my_list=[10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 15]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> sum(i+j==30 for i,j in combinations(my_list,2))
2
```

And if you want that items too you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [(i,j) for i,j in combinations(my_list,2) if i+j==30]
[(10, 20), (15, 15)]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 15]
>>> count = 0
>>> for x, y in combinations(lst, 2):
        if x + y == 30:
            print(x, y)
            count += 1

10 20
15 15

>>> print(count)
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you don't want to use itertools you could do it with the following list comprehension

```
 len([(ii,jj) for i, ii in enumerate(a) for j, jj in enumerate(a[i+1:]) if ii+jj==30])
```

which gives you

```
 len([(10, 20), (15, 15)]) = 2
```

The combinations approach runs at about half the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since this comes from a programming challenge, here is a solution that has linear complexity in the length of the list (using combinations will get you quadratic complexity):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def count_pairs_summing_to(lst, n):  
    element_counter = defaultdict(int)
    count = 0
    for x in lst:
        if (n - x) in element_counter:
            count += element_counter[n - x]
        element_counter[x] += 1
    return count
```

The idea is to make one pass over the data and to keep track of the elements we've seen before in a hash table. 
When we see a new element `x` we only need to know if we have seen `30 - x` before.
We also keep track of how many times we've seen each element to make sure we count duplicate pairs (e.g `count_pairs_summing_to([10, 10, 20, 25], 30)` should return 2.).

Some benchmarking:

```
lst = [10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 15]

%timeit sum(i+j==30 for i,j in combinations(lst,2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.35 µs per loop

%timeit len([(ii,jj) for i, ii in enumerate(lst) for j, jj in enumerate(lst[i+1:]) if ii+jj==30])
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.59 µs per loop

%timeit count_pairs_summing_to(lst, 30)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.92 µs per loop

# With a slightly bigger list.
import numpy.random as random
big_lst = list(random.randint(0, 100, size=1000))

%timeit len([(ii,jj) for i, ii in enumerate(big_lst) for j, jj in enumerate(big_lst[i+1:]) if ii+jj==30])
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

%timeit sum(i+j==30 for i,j in combinations(big_lst,2))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop

# The previous one was surprisingly slow but it can be fixed:
%timeit sum(1 for i,j in combinations(big_lst,2) if i+j==30)
1 loops, best of 3: 88.2 ms per loop

%timeit count_pairs_summing_to(big_lst, 30)
1000 loops, best of 3: 504 µs per loop
```